# get full path of all nodes in xml file using java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

i want to get full path of an xml file , using java ,
file is like this :

```
<root>
    <A>
        <A1>
            <A1A>1000</A1A>
            <A1B>2000</A1B>
            <A1C>3000</A1C>
        </A1>
        <A2>
            <A2A>4000</A2A>
            <A2B>5000</A2B>
        </A2>
    </A>
    <B>
        <B1>
            <B1A>6000</B1A>
        </B1>
    </B>
</root>
```

and result should be like this :

```
root/A/A1/A1A    1000
root/A/A1/A1B    2000
root/A/A1/A1C    3000
root/A/A2/A2A    4000
root/A/A2/A2B    5000
root/B/B1/B1A    6000
```

iteration of all nodes and getting their full path : 
this is code of begining , but i havnt till an idea about getting full path :

```
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/root/A/descendant::node()");
            NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nl.item(i);
                doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(doc.importNode(node, true));

// here i want extracting full path of each node
                System.out.print(node.getParentNode().getNodeName()+"\n");
            }
```

please could any one help me :)

Comment: NodeList is a DOM thing, XPathExpression is a JDOM thing. DOM and JDOM are not the same. You will be getting a ClassCastException when using `(NodeList)` because `evaluate(...)` returns a `List<Object>` in that context

Comment: it worked for me , the only thing i need , is displaying full path of each node